# Uploading files to Cloud Server

Tags: php, forms, upload, cloud

I am building a website where users can upload their photographs etc. For storing the data I am thinking of using a cloud server. I am a little confused about how the data will be uploaded on this server. Suppose, I have a form for a user to upload a photograph. So when the user uploads a photo using the form, php validates the input and directs it to a predefined path. In case of a cloud server, will what will this predefined path be? Will I get a sort of an address from the company providing the cloud services? Or will there be multiple addresses as data can be stored in different p

Comment: Are you talking about a CDN or a bunch of servers on which you can store files?

Comment: Why can't you just check it? If you can't understand how cloud hosting works, use normal hosting (e.g. linode.com).

Answer (score 1):

figure out what service you are going to use, AWS S3 is pretty good, as you wont even know if its possible till then. examples of do it below

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/